# add numeric values of diffrent row and columns using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table named data with fields id, user_id , qtn_id , ans, status. I want to get the total sum of the correct and wrong ans in another table for a specific user id.

Here is a rough example of table from where I want to get my data.
Status 1 means right answer and 0 is for wrong ans.

```
id   user_id  qtn_id   ans     status

1       1       1      opt3      1

2       1       2      opt2      1   

3       1       3      opt1      0

4       4       3      opt2      1

5       4       4      opt4      0

6       4       1      opt3      1
```

And I want to insert data in other table for eg like this

```
id   user_id     total_wright_ans   total_wrongs_ans     

1       1          4                   2                                               

2       2          3                   3 

3       3          1                   5                                               

4       4          3                   3
```

How can I do this with the help of PHP and MySQL?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Check out the MySQL SUM() function:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm

Comment: Using `SUM()` and `COUNT()` you won't need the other table

Comment: i need ...someone gave me a task...so have to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try below MYSQL code

SELECT COUNT( STATUS ) AS total_wright_ans, user_id, SUM( STATUS = 0 ) AS total_wrongs_ans
FROM  `TABLE1` 
GROUP BY user_id

Loop through the above query it will returns the results set. Hope this will help you